# Can a sound be re-created from FFT?

Tags: fft

I'm studying some FFT code's and I'm looking for the possibility to recreate a (cycling) sound that as been decomposed with a fast fourrier transform.
I tried by adding several sinuzoidal curves but it doesn't work at all.
I'm working with C++ but any help will be welcomed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that have to answer my question alone... also I understood that the IFFT was what I looked for,I found a slower function but perfect for me:

```
void inverseDFT(const double *a, const double *b, const int &N, double *&s)
{
     // note: this code is not optimised at all, written for clarity not speed.
     for (int x = 0; x < N; ++x)
     {
         s[x] = a[0];
         for (int k = 1; k <= N / 2; ++k)
         {
             s[x] += a[k] * cos(2 * M_PI / N * k * x) + b[k] * sin(2 * M_PI / N * k * x);
         }
     }
 }
```

It works perfectly, maybe it will help someone else.